# Searching for alphanumeric passwords in regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have been trying to create a Regex that can detect alphanumeric passwords between 5-20 characters in lengths. These passwords can contain special characters (`@$!%*#?&£`). My attempts either don't detect all of my test cases or they generate a large number of false positives.

The Regex currently looks like this:

```
\b(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d*)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&£]*)[a-zA-Z\d@$!%*#?&£]{5,20}(?<![a-zA-Z ])\b
```

[Here is my Regex running on Regexr with my test cases](https://regexr.com/4fhe8)

The criteria for the Regex is as follows:

- Detect mixed alpha numeric words between 5 & 20 chars long
- Detect special symbols (`@$!%*#?&£` etc)

When writing the original regex I encountered alot of problems getting the character boundary to apply, say if a word is 21 characters I wouldn't want it getting detected at all. I essentially only want to scan items between this length, but this boundary has stopped many matches getting detected.

Take the strings "Rese7" & "Rese7A".
The first string matches && the second doesnt, I suspect this is because of how I have implemented the character checking. I basically want the regex to do the following things:

- Define words as any characters (including special)
- Look for words between 5-20 characters in length
- Check if they are alpha numeric (`aA-zZ0-9!£$` etc)
- Only match words that fulfill this criteria

I'm not sure if I', thinking about this right, I had a look at other alphanumeric password questions and the answers didn't look to satisfy my test cases:

- [There were only 2 regex answers on this but they didnt work in RegExr...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195665/regex-for-alphanumeric-password-with-at-least-1-number-and-character)
- [This isn't complex enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740275/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-one-non-alphanumeric-character)
- [Nothing on here worked despite it being well explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997616/regex-for-password-that-requires-one-numeric-or-one-non-alphanumeric-character)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|[^a-zA-Z\d@$!%*#?&£])[a-zA-Z\d@$!%*#?&£]{5,20}(?:$|[^a-zA-Z\d@$!%*#?&£])
```

What you need is the beginning of the string `^` or not one of your matchable characters `[^a-zA-Z\d@$!%*#?&£]` followed by 5 to 20 matchable characters `[a-zA-Z\d@$!%*#?&£]{5,20}` followed by the end of the string `$` or one non matchable character `[^a-zA-Z\d@$!%*#?&£]` again.

Regexs are as much about what you don't want as what you do

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern you use these positive lookaheads`(?=.*\d*)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&£]*)`  where what you want to assert should match 0+ times a digit or a special char using the asterix `*`.

So the assertion would be true if it is or is not there, which will always be true giving you much more matches than you would expect.

You could use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string and leave out the `*` to match it at least 1 times to make sure it is there.

The negative lookbehind at the end `(?<![a-zA-Z ])` makes sure that what is on the left is not a char a-zA-Z or a space. You can omit this by not allowing a space to match.

But enforcing this rule would not allow `rese7FwDdvgfe` to match but in your example data you do want to match it so you can leave the lookbehind out of the pattern.

```
^(?=[^a-zA-Z\s]*[a-zA-Z])(?=(?:[^\d\s]*\d|[^\s@$!%*#?&£]*[@$!%*#?&£]))[@$!%*#?&£a-zA-Z\d]{5,20}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?=[^a-zA-Z\s]*[a-zA-Z])` Assert upper or lower case a-z
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `[^\d\s]*\d` Assert a digit
    - `|` Or
    - `[^\s@$!%*#?&£]*[@$!%*#?&£]` Assert a special char
  - `)` Close non capturing group
- `)` Close positive lookahead
- `[@$!%*#?&£a-zA-Z\d]{5,20}` Match all of the allowed 5 - 20 times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OEsWMz/1)